Simplified Formulas for calculating the electron mass
I've been studying the 2019 paper by Nassim Haramein where he uses a surface to volume ratio to calculate the mass of an electron.
I know the theory is debatable, but that's not what my question is about. It's about the formula in figure 20. I was simplifying equation by hand (and checking it in Javascript using a bignumber library), and I want to get a second opinion on this calculation.
If I'm understanding it correctly, it seems to simplify down to the following calculation.
$$
\frac{1}{2 a} \cdot \frac{4 L_h}{2 r} \cdot M_h = \frac{L_h M_h}{a r} = \frac{h}{2 \pi c a r} = \frac{\hbar / c}{a r} = m_e
$$

$( L_h )$ is the planck mass
$( M_h )$ is the planck length
$( h $) is the Planck constant
$( c $) is the speed of light
$( a )$ is the fine structure constant
$( r )$ is the Bohr radius

I'm not even going to ask if this is simplified correctly, because I already checked it in Javascript and it gives me the same answer to extreme precision.
Why does this formula simplify down to these constants? Why these constants? Why would this formula calculate the mass of an electron?
In case you're curious, the answer I'm getting is 9.1093837077672585...e-31 kg.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
